# Rails schema & migrate keeps reverting to a VERSION=0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Here is the basics. I had a deployment on a SANDBOX environment.

I made some changes, and attempted to redeploy. The Stack is Cap3 with a Postgres DB / Rails 4.2

Upon deployment, which has never had any issues prior, when it came to run the migrations, which it shouldn't have because there were no pending ones, it basically rolled back all of the migrations to a 0 state.

I successfully created this error in the development environment.
I had to recover the schema file from a previous commit, because the reversion of course rolled everything back.

so right now.

`ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151214201502) do ...`

And the last migration file is
`20151214201502_create_host_group_membership_table`

When I try and deploy, or run `rake db:migrate` I get a total reversion. All tables get dropped.

Schema.rb reads `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do`

and the `rake db:migrate:status` reads >

```
Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
  down    20150916151324  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20150916190627  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20150916195012  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20150918112956  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20151019175551  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20151020195644  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20151020202321  Create ...<edited> table 
  down    20151026021111  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20151124161525  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20151124185807  Create ...<edited> table
  down    20151214201502  Create ...<edited> table
```

and any subsequent rake db:migrate results in nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you overwrite the ENV["VERSION"], the `rake db:migrate` will go downgrade rather than upgrade if VERSION is smaller than last known VERSION in db schema, so please check and avoid similar environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what happened. Forgot to update the ticket. Thanks for the answer. 

Seems odd that such a common keyword would be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, but Eric's answer didn't work in my case.
What did the trick was to drop the db, erase the schema and create and migrate the db:

```
$ rails db:drop
$ rm db/schema.rb
$ rails db:create
$ rails db:migrate
```